# Altering an Infinite Set does not change cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

Let X be an infinite set. Show that adding or subtracting a single point does not change its cardinality.

I have a plan but need help writing the actual proof. 
I need to show that it doesn't matter which point is removed, and then I can use the fact that X is in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset to prove this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the infinite set, $Y \subset X$ the set for which there's a bijection $Y \rightarrow X$ (which means $|Y|=|X|$), and $x$ some element in $X$.
Since there's at least one element "missing" in $Y$: 
$$|X|=|Y| \leq |X- \{x\}|$$
Using the same reasoning:
$$|X- \{x\}| \leq |X|$$
Conclusion:
$$|X- \{x\}| = |X|$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* show that there exists an injective map $\omega\to X$. Then it is possible to "hide" a single point by shifting $\omega$ up/down.

Comment: Could you elaborate further please? I understand what you're hinting at but I'm not sure how to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Given two elements $x,y\in X$ there is a permutation of $X$, $\pi$, such that $\pi(x)=y$ and $\pi(y)=x$.

Comment: How does that help in answering the question? I was trying to prove the same fact and the proof I thought of was the same as the one which Hagen Von Eitzen points to above. But I still interested in understanding how your hint solves the problem.

Comment: From the question, "and then I can use the fact that X is in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset to prove this." Fix one such subset of $X$, call it $Y$. Now given any $x\in X$ use the hint to find an injection from $X\setminus\{x\}$ into $Y$; and if $x\notin X$ use the hint to find an injection from $X\cup\{x\}$ into $Y\cup\{y\}$ for some $y\in X\setminus Y$.

Comment: Can this be done without choice?

Comment: @Math: Adding a point to an infinite set? No, it is consistent that there are infinite sets that are strictly larger than any of their proper subsets. Finding a permutation changing two points? Yes. That's doable without choice.

Comment: I meant the first one; thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it can be proven in ZFC that adding or removing an element from an infinite set never changes its cardinality but it cannot be proven in ZF. In ZFC, it can be proven as follows. From the axiom of choice, we can derive the axiom of dependent choice. Using the axiom of dependent choice, we can show that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset. For any infinite set, since it has a countably infinite subset, adding or removing an element doesn't change its cardinality.

What really is cardinality? ZFC doesn't really formally define the cardinality of any set. However, we can informally define the cardinality of any set to be the smallest ordinal number such that there's a bijection from that set to that ordinal number. That's what the mathematical community decided they mean when they talk about the cardinality of a set in ZFC.