# show that non degeneracy sets are equipotent between them.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cardinals, simple-functions

I have to prove it for these sets and find a bijection:

a)
$(a,b) \sim [a,b] \sim [a,b) \sim (a,b]$

where: $a,b\in R$

with $a<b$

b)
$[a,b] \sim [c,d]$

where: $a,b,c,d \in R$

with $a<b ,c<d$

I know that:

> Two sets are said to be 'equipotent' if there is a bijection between
>   them

for a)
 $f: (a,b) -> [a,b]$

$f(x)=x/\vert x\vert$

for the b) I've found on some notes (without showing why), that a good bijection could be the map:
$f(x)=kx+(c-ak)$

where:

$k =\frac{d-c}{b-a}$

I need how to show the assert and a write a bijection

Comment: You could try to prove the more general assertion that "removing finitely many points from an infinite set doesn't change its cardinality".

Comment: found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665111/altering-an-infinite-set-does-not-change-cardinality
what do I have to show then (for creating a bijection..)?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a set, $|A|$ is its cardinality.

The map $f \colon [a,b] \to [c,d]$ that you defined for (b) is bijective because it is the straight line of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains the points $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ (verify that $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$).

For (a), notice that, being $(a,b) \subset [a,b]$, it holds that $|(a,b)| \leq |[a,b]|$. Now consider $c,d$ such that $a < c < d < b$. Then $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$ and $|[c,d]| \leq |(a,b)|$. Since $f$ of (b) is a bijection $[a,b] \to [c,d]$, it holds that $|[a,b]|=|[c,d]| \leq |(a,b)|$. Being $|(a,b)| \leq |[a,b]|$ and $|[a,b]| \leq |(a,b)|$, by Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder Theorem there is a bijection $[a,b] \to (a,b)$.

Notice that $(a,b) \subset [a,b) \subset [a,b]$. Then $|(a,b)| \leq |[a,b)| \leq |[a,b]|=|(a,b)|$. By the same Theorem, there is a bijection $[a,b) \to (a,b)$. We can do the same for $(a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect! A bijection $[a,b)->(a,b)$ could be $f(x)=b$ if $x=a$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is not $a$ ? It is the easiest that came to my mind

Comment: or is it there another  bijective function? don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: No, that one cannot be a bijection $[a,b) \to (a,b)$, since $a \mapsto b$ and $b$ does not belong to the set $(a,b)$. Rather, it is a bijection $[a,b) \to (a,b]$.

Comment: I still don't understand why it is a bijection only for $[a,b)->(a,b]$ (trying to figure it out with a drawing)

Comment: You said $f \colon [a,b) \to (a,b)$ such that $f(a) =b$. How could this be a map $[a,b) \to (a,b)$ if $f(a) =b $ is not even an element of the codomain $(a,b)$? The image of any map is contained in its codomain, but this is not the case: the image $(a,b]$ of $f$ is not contained in its codomain $(a,b)$.

Comment: Is it ok? If it isn't I can try to explain it again